# I can't install packages for Python with Homebrew

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, homebrew

I use this statement '$ brew install python' to install Python, and then I type this statement '$ pip install virtualenvwrapper'. It shows:

```
    -bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why. And I type this statement again '$ brew install python', it shows:

```
    Warning: python-2.7.10_2 already installed, it's just not linked
```

Why Python is not linked? Does this problem cause the virtualenvwrapper can't be installed? I have uninstalled Python many times. But I still cannot install packages for Python.

Here is my computer information. Mac OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5, and the Python version I installed through homebrew is 2.7.10.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install(overwrite current installation) python again

```
brew link --overwrite python
```

Comment: You don't need to install pip; Homebrew's python distribution includes pip. If you *did* need to install pip (and you don't), you should use [get-pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and not easy_install, and you should never use sudo with Homebrew.